# Ternary operator in actualization of a loop

Tags: c#, loops, ternary

I am trying to make **two loops into one**.  This Loop should go through the array from the beginning to the end and otherwise. However my increment is not correct. Can anyone help? T**hank you in advance.**

```
for (int i = ((asc == true) ? 0 : calendar.Length - 1);
    ((asc == true) ? i < calendar.Length : i > 0); 
    (asc==true) ? i++ : i--)
```

Comment: good lord that's hard to read

Comment: *Why* are you trying to make two loops into one? And why are you comparing with `true` instead of just using `asc` as the condition? Fundamentally, you're trying to abuse the conditional operator...

Comment: I would be very upset if I saw this code in production. Just use `Reverse` for goodness sake.

Comment: short is not always the best solution ;)

Comment: Always post the full error message(s). Your code does not compile, that's not very clear from "my increment is not correct".

Comment: You are trying to make compact code but you have "== true" not once but 3 times? It's an entirely unnecessary clause if 'asc' is a Boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the C# reference of "for": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx

Specifically:

The iterator section defines what happens after each iteration of the body of the loop. The iterator section contains zero or more of the following statement expressions, separated by commas:

- assignment statement
- invocation of a method
- prefix or postfix increment expression, such as ++i or i++
- prefix or postfix decrement expression, such as --i or i--
- creation of an object by using new
- await expression

The expression: "(asc==true) ? i++ : i--" is none of these things.

Therefore, you'd want the assignment: i += (asc ? 1 : -1)

```
for (int i = ((asc) ? 0 : calendar.Length - 1);
      ((asc) ? i < calendar.Length : i >= 0); 
      i += (asc) ? 1 : -1)
```

Incidentally, as pointed out in comment, you'll probably want to look at index 0 in the condition, so your condition statement in the "descending" case should be i >= 0 (reflected in the code).

Comment: It should also be `i >= 0`.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I find that *very* hard to read, as well as invalid (it won't compile) - because you're trying to use the conditional operator as a statement expression, when it's not. Personally, I'd write something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < calendar.Length; i++)
{
    int index = asc ? i : calendar.Length - 1 - i;
    // Now use index...
}
```

Making *three different aspects* all conditional feels like a nasty way to go.

Comment: I think you meant to subtract `i` at the end instead of `index`.

Comment: I don't see where the conditional op is used as a statement, `for(a;b;c)` requires 3 expressions.

Comment: @Henk: the second is an expression, but I think the first and third have to be statements. Will check tonight.

Comment: You're kind of right, it should be "zero or more statement expressions". The OP's code does not compile, that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4):

Jon offered a good option, but if principle:

```
for (int i = (asc ? 0 : calendar.Length - 1);
     asc ? i < calendar.Length : i >= 0; 
     i += asc?1:-1)
{
            //body
}
```

Comment: This does fix the fundamental issue with the original code.  And the irritating one of comparing a `bool` to `true`.

Comment: To be fair, you're making an assumption that it's not a comparison against a System.Nullable<bool>.

Answer (score 1):

That for loop is... odd. It is also very hard to read. In the spirit of "better ways to do this", I would suggest just using `Reverse`:

```
IEnumerable<Day> collection = asc ? calendar : calendar.Reverse();

for (int i = 0; i < calendar.Length; i++)
{
    collection.ElemantAt(i);// This is the current element
}

//Or better, you are getting everything anyways:
foreach (Day day in collection)
{
}
```